# Using jQuery Plugin Hooks

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm using this jquery to display some information on hover:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.promo_slider_wrapper').hover(function() {
            jQuery('.promo_slider_excerpt').animate({right: 0, opacity: 1}, 500 );
        },
        function() {
            jQuery('.promo_slider_excerpt').animate({right: -320, opacity: 1}, 500 );
    });
});
```

I'm using this on the "Promotion Slider" Wordpress plugin, and it works great. Only the client want the information to be shown on slide load, instead of on hover. The plugin I'm using has a "action hook" that is called on the slide load. The action hook is "promoslider_content".

So how do I use "promoslider_content" action hook to trigger the animation instead of my current "hover" function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this by editing the plugin (then changing the plugin name so they don't update it and overwrite my customization). It's not the best solution, but it worked.

promo_slider.js (starting at line 161):

```
// Add / Remove classes
currentItem.removeClass('current');
jQuery('.promo_slider_excerpt').animate({right: -260, opacity: 1}, 200 );
newItem.addClass('current');
currentSpan.removeClass('current');
newSpan.addClass('current');

// Fade in / out
currentItem.fadeOut('fast', function(){
newItem.fadeIn('fast');
jQuery('.promo_slider_excerpt').animate({right: 0, opacity: 1}, 500 );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the hover part, then you should be able to just include the function contents, which will run this immediately.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.promo_slider_excerpt').animate({right: 0, opacity: 1}, 500 );
});
```

But then the animation won't return back to `-320`, which would have normally happened when you moved the mouse out. You could setup some type of interval timer to do this.

Comment: That doesn't work because it only animates on the first slide. When a new slides fade in, it just sits there and the content changes. I'm thinking that's where this action hook comes it. The timer would probably work but it's dynamic (the user can change the slide time from the cms), so I'm trying not to hard code that.